# How to convert below XML to Java Object in Java

Tags: java, xml, spring, xml-parsing, xml-to-json

I want to read the values under value tag
i.e. **Yes**, **750,3500**,  **AL**,**Real**, **Approved**, **G**, **140**, **GT**  these values i want to map with java object.

```
    <entities>
<entity id="1234" userId="RD" parent="TestID">
    <name>AL</name>
    <values>
        <value id="testA" id="Y">Yes</value>
        <value id="testB">750</value>
        <value id="testC">3500</value>
        <value id="testD">AL</value>
        <value id="testE">Real</value>
        <value id="testF" ID="A" Changed="true">Approved</value>
        <value id="testF">G</value>
        <value id="testG">140</value>
        <value id="testF">GT</value>
    </values>
</entity>
</entities>
```

Comment: ok. and what is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: I'm able to map other element (id,userId, id ) with @XmlAttribute but not able tp map inside <value>element</value>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Jaxb` library like below.

Entities.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entities")
public class Entities {
    @XmlElement(name = "entity")
    private List<Entity> entityList;
}
```

Entity.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entity")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entity {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "userId")
    private String userId;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "parent")
    private String parent;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "values")
    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private List<Value> valueList;
}
```

Value.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "value")
public class Value {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "ID")
    private String ID;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Changed")
    private String changed;

    @XmlValue
    private String text;
}
```

You can see how to use `Jaxb` library in the reference below.

> https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb